# where to search for work as freelancer?

Tags: marketing

The first responses will be the Freelancer.com, fiver, and upwork.com.
This sites are paying very low and for a job, which is impossible to do it or illegal, for an example:

> We are looking for apple apps developer to
> update our app with the new apple guide lines, apple remove it from
> apps store when we fail to update it time.
>
> If you can not download the original copy from apple developer
> dashboard, you may have to convert android copy to IOS app.

Now, go and do the bid battle to decompile the Android and make an iOS app, well ... :)

I was asked to sign an NDA and only than it will be delivered the details. I tought I have found a  serious client. The detail it was: download an Android app, decompile it, change the logo and  recompile it, well,  I didn't and I don't want to do it such things.

The second anwers it will be: toptal.com and they alternatives.
The toptal has the marketing text "we have the top 3%" , yeas agree, on some cases...
And I can build a test system, which will adjust the dificulty and the time to bypass only the 3%. Simple.  That is completly different thing when and how much time it is used those algorithms, when I need to write code.

The third are the job sites and Linked in.
They are full with HR, who are lookig for people, who want to be employed: "full time" or "permanent" as how it says in UK. And is USA: "anywhere in USA", but I live in EU and I have my own company, I do accounting and  I don't want employment.

The fourth type is the outsourcing. They are loking for teams the huge companies, corporates, there is no "build me a software with specifications like this:" -at least I don't know where should I find it, but other companies make a living and many times just 1 developer is assigned for the project.

The word of mounth: I have asked my friends and my fiends "friends" if we name it. One problem could be, if you live in a country, where 1 windows license (of 100 euro ) it is enough for the whole street, they proably are't interested in my "custom software developement" for thousands of euro!
While compared to a local job the costs of producing the same amount of work it would be then thousands.

At UK jobs is very opular to work with recruiters and the "employer" gets thousands of candidates ( but is paying daily 500-700 euro)
At USA almost the same, but is writen "Anywhere in USA" and they don't care if I am telling  I don't need emplyment, nhence neither VISA, and  Ican work with they timezone.

So simply I can't find a single company, were the software is needed and they have 10k-50k euro budget and nobody want to be my boss with any price.
I run out from ideas, that's why I am asking help as ideas.

Comment: In many cases, we find clients through personal interactions - I know someone who knows someone with a problem. Marketing is very different from programming in that it is indeterminate. We take actions and they don't produce results. Yet, if we don't take actions, we don't get results. When we take marketing actions, results come from nothing we did. The marketing you do that gets results will often be different from what I do.

Comment: How does **any** company find customers? Advertising.

Comment: @Scott at the Advertising and marketing there is "a thing" named cost: per new client. If I can earn 20k euro from a new client and the cost for that is 50k, than better I go to sleep and do nothing, because it is more profitable :)

Comment: Gotta spend money to make money. Spin your comment.. if a new client brings 20K.. it's worth the 1K it cost to acquire them... You *may* be doing **nothing** to advertise. No one said you need to *start* with a 50K ad budget. There's an old adage... In bad times one MUST advertise, in good times one SHOULD advertise.

Answer (score 3):

Make professional contacts. See if there are ways that you can display your work. Build off your existing clients who are satisfied. The successful small business entrepreneurs I know have all built business off good contacts. Other ways include volunteering for tech events and projects. The aim is to get word of mouth referrals. Some of my best clients have come through professional--and personal--contacts. This is a kind of warm intro, as contrasted to a cold intro, which is what happens when you deal with total strangers.

Comment: Thanks for idea, but...Personal professional contracts... well, some see the half empty part of the glass :)) "Some" are not interested, some are not serious, some doesn't want to pay, some would add to infinite change requests and implement new features."some" have shame to tell me they don't know how to use a smartphone, even if they has a million euro company, so the software is bad and it will reveal this huge shame. "some" thinks they will not able to earn black money using software. "some" managers are stealing from company and a software would reveal it, but the CEO sends me to manager!

Comment: Everyone encounters bad or inexperienced clients. You have such a large percentage that I have to assume you are looking in the wrong places. It appears to me that you need to find a more technical audience. You need to find a more ethical audience. You can take care of scope creep by putting change orders in the front of a contract. If you are in a country where the overwhelming number of potential clients are unethical you need to look for clients in other countries. Not easy but doable. Hope this helps.